# Disabling Logging in Sphinx Documentation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, documentation, python-sphinx

I use jupyter notebooks and build Sphinx documentation out of it. I set the `nbsphinx_execute = 'always'` This would print all the log messages from the code I am executing in the documentation.

I know I can disable logging from each notebook, but is there a way to disable the logging globally?